# Generating an array of random numbers using web_sys

Tags: rust, webassembly

I am trying to populate a vector with random numbers using `web_sys` crate

Something like this :

```
extern crate web_sys;

use web_sys::Crypto;    

// ...

fn main() {
    // ...

    let mut arry = [0u8; 128];
    let crypto = Crypto::new();
    crypto.get_random_values_with_u8_array(&mut arry)

    // ...
}
```

The `Crypto` struct however does not implement `new` methods and docs do not mention the fields needed to instantiate the the struct.

I've included `Crypto` as feature in my `Cargo.toml` file:

```
[dependencies.web-sys]
 version = "0.3"
 features = [
   "Crypto"
 ]
```

Here's the relevant docs page:

https://docs.rs/web-sys/0.3.35/i686-unknown-linux-gnu/web_sys/struct.Crypto.html

Does anyone have experience using this?

Comment: The *web_sys* crate is generated automatically from the browser's *WebIDL*. According to https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Crypto there doesn't seem to be any field to instantiate in this struct

Comment: @VictorDeleau I get a compiler error however on `let c = Crypto {}`  - missing field `obj`

Comment: *This API requires the following crate features to be activated: Crypto*. Did you do so?

Comment: Yes, I've updated my question with the relevant section of Cargo.toml

Comment: @aj_opinv if you look at the documentation you linked, it is an opaque struct and doesn't have a `new` method. Meaning you're supposed to obtain an instance from somewhere else, which makes a lot of sense because the `crypto` web API is essentially a *module*. In the WebIDL you access it via `Window.crypto`, not by creating your own instance. [If you look for crypto in the documentation](https://docs.rs/web-sys/0.3.44/i686-unknown-linux-gnu/web_sys/index.html?search=crypto) you'll find `Window::crypto`, and a `Window` can be obtained by calling the `window()` global function.

Comment: Therefore I'd expect you need something like `web_sys::window().crypto()` (and that's a `Result` so you need to handle the possibility of this failing).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks Masklinn's comment, I was able to get this to work by getting an instance of Window and calling `crypto` on it.

```
let mut rand_arry = [0u8; 128];
let window_instance = web_sys::window().unwrap();
let crypto = window_instance.crypto.unwrap();
crypto.get_random_values_with_u8_array(&mut rand_arry).unwrap();
```

Make sure to declare `Crypto` and `Window` as web-sys features

```
[dependencies.web-sys]
version = "0.3"
features = [
    "Window",
    "Crypto"
]
```